# Program comes out with an error after ignoring a %s in C

Tags: c

I was trying to make a file editor. This is a snippet of a bigger program. I tried ignoring a %s which was inside an fprintf by using a back slash (\)

```
#include <stdio>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
        FILE * writetable;
        writetable = fopen("test.c", "w");
        fprintf(writetable, "#include <stdio.h>\n");
        fprintf(writetable, "#include <string.h>\n");
        fprintf(writetable, "#include <stdlib.h>\n");
        fprintf(writetable, "int conten(void) {\n");
        fprintf(writetable, "   char* file1[50] = \"");
        fprintf(writetable, "%s", filename);
        fprintf(writetable, "\";\n   printf(\"\%s\" file1);");
        fprintf(writetable, "\n}");
}
```

And it comes out with something like this:

```
writer.c: In function ‘main’:
writer.c:104:49: warning: format ‘%s’ expects a matching ‘char *’ argument [-Wformat=]
  104 |         fprintf(writetable, "\";\n   printf(\"\%s\" file1);");
      |                                               ~~^
      |                                                 |
      |                                                 char *
```

Can someone tell me what is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: It's impossible to tell from a snippet what the problem might be with your bigger program. The code in your question won't compile, both because you have `<stdio>` rather than `<stdio.h>` and because `filename` is undeclared. Read this: [mre]

Comment: @KeithThompson, even if the code is technically not a "minimal, reproducible example", it is totally possible to to tell what the problem is based on the error message.

Comment: @HAL9000 Probably, but I like to encourage good habits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "%" is not being escaped, because it's not treated as a special character.

You can either use just "%%" instead, or "\045"

```
fprintf(writetable, "\";\n   printf(\"%%s\" file1);");
```

Comment: `\045` won't work. That's still a single `%` character passed to `printf`.

Comment: Just a small tip: If you don't intend to do formatted output, and just want to print the string "as is", this whole problem can be avoided by using `fputs`.

Comment: @HAL9000 So long as you want the new line which `fputs()` appends.  There isn't one in this case (though the OPs code has one at the _beginning_ of the next output).

Comment: @Clifford, `fputs` doesn't add a trailing newline. You are probably confusing it with `puts`, which I agree is broken, and *do* add a newline.

Comment: @HAL9000 Nope; I was confusing it with fgets() .  :-/

Answer (score 0):

Header file use extension "#include<stdio.h>"

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer to the question.  You can post _comments _to the question in SO, but you should not post an answer for this.  Delete and add a comment instead.  SO is a Q&A not a discussion forum.

Comment: The answer: I cut this out of a bigger program but forgot to put the ".h" as I was reconstructing it as a smaller program.